# Boolean Value on Filter in Angular Not Returning Records

Tags: angularjs

I am currently in an angular/node environment. I have added the boolean value of true to my filter such that I get an exact match (I am using angular 1.5.5). however, when I add this value no records show. I am curious as to why this is, as both fields that are supposed to match are of the same data type and there are no other errors.
Here is the line that is giving trouble:

```
<tr ng-repeat="call in calls | filter:{clientid:clientiD}:true | orderBy:'createdAt'">
```

Where clientid is an integer field of the call table, and clientiD is defined as so:

```
$scope.clientiD = document.location.href.split('callog/')[1];
```

Where it is getting the parameter of the client id from the client table, which too is an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in boolean exact mutch, but in expression of filter. You can fix it this way:
In a view: `ng-repeat="call in calls | filter:callsFilter:true | orderBy:'createdAt'"`
And in controller:

```
$scope.callsFilter = {clientid:document.location.href.split('callog/')[1]};
```

**Update**:
The original expression didn't work because angular treated `clientiD` in `{clientid:clientiD}` as value and not as variable on `$scope`

**Update2** 
Assuming `clientid` is of type `Number` - string value extracted from location should be converted to this type for exact match:

```
var clientId = parseInt(document.location.href.split('callog/')[1];
$scope.callsFilter = {clientid:clientId};
```

Comment: Why didn't the structure of the filter work? According to the angular docs that is the accepted format

Comment: See updated answer. Also have a look at `ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict` example in [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: Unfortunately, when adding `ng-repeat="call in calls | filter:callsFilter:true | orderBy:'createdAt'"` it still does not show any records

Comment: Works without the true condition

Comment: also `document.location.href.split('callog/')[1]` is of type `String`. So if `clientid` is `Number` this will not work obviously.

Comment: Well, there isn't much to put, but I did make a Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Joberman/nre0cqom/1/

Comment: can I make `document.location.href.split('callog/')[1] into an integer?

Comment: sure - use parseInt function: `parseInt(document.location.href.split('callog/')[1])`

Comment: Okay, yes I have used parseInt and it works perfectly. Please revise your answer to reflect this so I can mark it as proper solution. Thank you